# How to bind @PathVariable value to @Where clause in Spring boot rest API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I am reading @PathVaraible in Controller and using `@Where` annotation in Entity. If I pass hardcoded value to `@Where` clause in Entity it is working fine. But I want to pass run time value which is passed in `@PathVariable` to @Where in Entity.

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/course/details/{courseId}")
    public List<CourseDto> getcourseDetails(@Valid @PathVariable final String courseId) {
        // lines of code
        }

@Entity
@Where(clause="course_id=:courseId")
public class CourseEntity{
@NotBlank(message = "Please provide courseId)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar(50)",length = 50)
    private String courseId;

}

@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<Course, Integer> {
 

}
```

With this code I am getting error as

> Incorrect syntax near ':'.

How to fix this error. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: I think you should create a separate method to your repository like `getAllByCourseId(String courseId)` for such purpose

Comment: Do I need to pass any parameter to this method? e.g  `public String getAllByCourseId( @param("someId") String courseId)`.

Comment: @Alex can you please share some example for this

Comment: Attach your `CourseEntity` repository please if it exists

Comment: just for notice - as far as i know you can't use dynamic expression in `@Where` annotation. So you should create separate method to query your enitity using filter by courseId. It may be autogenerated method for `JpaRepository` or some method with custom query

Comment: You should check spring data reference - you'll find there an answer https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change a `@Where` clause at runtime. If you want to set a parameter you can use `@Filter`:

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(
    name="courseFilter",
    parameters=@ParamDef(
        name="courseId",
        type="int"
    )
)
@Filter(
    name="firstAccounts",
    condition="course_id=:courseId"
)
public class CourseEntity{
   ...
}
```

Now with the Hibernate ORM session or entity manager you can  set a parameter the following way:

```
entityManager
    .unwrap( Session.class )
    .enableFilter( "courseFilter" )
    .setParameter( "courseId", ...);

List<CourseEntity> courses = entityManager
    .createQuery("from CourseEntity c", CourseEntity.class)
    .getResultList();
```

The Hibernate ORM documentation has [more details about filtering entities](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filtering) using `@Filter` or `@Where`.